# Go crawler stalls on select from output channel after a few minutes

Tags: go, blocking, channel, goroutine

I've written a simple crawler that looks something like this:

```
type SiteData struct {
    // ...
}

func downloadURL(url string) (body []byte, status int) {
    resp, err := http.Get(url)

    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    status = resp.StatusCode
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    body, err = ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    body = bytes.Trim(body, "\x00")

    return
}


func processSiteData(resp []byte) SiteData {
    // ...
}    

func worker(input chan string, output chan SiteData) {

    // wait on the channel for links to process
    for url := range input {

        // fetch the http response and status code
        resp, status := downloadURL(url)

        if resp != nil && status == 200 {
            // if no errors in fetching link
            // process the data and send 
            // it back
            output <- processSiteData(resp)
        } else {
            // otherwise send the url for processing
            // once more
            input <- url
        }
    }
}

func crawl(urlList []string) {
    numWorkers := 4
    input := make(chan string)
    output := make(chan SiteData)

    // spawn workers
    for i := 0; i < numWorkers; i++ {
        go worker(input, output)
    }

    // enqueue urls
    go func() {
        for url := range urlList {
            input <- url
        }
    }()

    // wait for the results
    for {
        select {
        case data := <-output:
            saveToDB(data)
        }
    }

}

func main() {
    urlList := loadLinksFromDB()
    crawl(urlList)
}
```

It scrapes a single website and works great - downloading data, processing it and saving it to a database. Yet after a few minutes (5-10) or so it gets "stuck" and needs to be restarted. The site isn't blacklisting me, I've verified with them and can access any url at any time after the program blocks. Also, it blocks *before* all the urls are done processing. Obviously it'll block when the list is spent, but it is nowhere near that.

Am I doing something wrong here? The reason I'm using `for { select { ... } }` instead of `for _, _ = range urlList { // read output }` is that any url can be re-enqueued if failed to process. In addition, the database doesn't seem to be the issue here as well. Any input will help - thanks.

Comment: When you say "stuck" do you mean it's deadlocking (and panicking) or simply hanging?

Comment: Just hang - no panic or crash. Thanks.

Comment: I'm rather confused; I can see a couple of cases (@dato points one out below) where this could deadlock, but in that case it would panic, not hang. (In fact it is odd to see a Go program truly hang, since that typically indicates deadlock). The best I can suggest is to put in some print statements and try and trace where it's stopping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this hangs when you have all N workers waiting on `input <- url`, and hence there are no more workers taking stuff out of `input`. In other words, if 4 URLs fail roughly at the same time, it will hang.

The solution is to send failed URLs to some place that is not the input channel for the workers (to avoid deadlock).

One possibility is to have a separate `failed` channel, with the anonymous goroutine always accepting input from it. Like this (**not tested**):

```
package main

func worker(intput chan string, output chan SiteData, failed chan string) {
    for url := range input {
        // ...
        if resp != nil && status == 200 {
            output <- processSideData(resp)
        } else {
            failed <- url
        }
    }
}

func crawl(urlList []string) {
    numWorkers := 4
    input := make(chan string)
    failed := make(chan string)
    output := make(chan SiteData)

    // spawn workers
    for i := 0; i < numWorkers; i++ {
        go worker(input, output, failed)
    }

    // Dispatch URLs to the workers, also receive failures from them.
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case input <- urlList[0]:
                urlList = urlList[1:]
            case url := <-failed:
                urlList = append(urlList, url)
            }
        }
    }()

    // wait for the results
    for {
        data := <-output
        saveToDB(data)
    }
}

func main() {
    urlList := loadLinksFromDB()
    crawl(urlList)
}
```

(Note how it is correct, as you say in your commentary, not to use `for _, _ = range urlList { // read output }` in your `crawl()` function, because URLs can be re-enqueued; but you don’t need select either as far as I can tell.)

Comment: I believe this would lead to a deadlock and thus a panic though, which is not what appears to be happening.

Comment: Oh, true. Deadlocks lead to panics, had forgotten about that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Curiously, using a different channel for the failed jobs seemed to have solved deadlock problem. I would add `if len(urlList) > 1 { urlList = urlList[:1] }` to prevent crash on empty slice, but otherwise it works. I'm puzzled as to why this deadlock occurs (or why is it even possible with select/channels), but otherwise - very nice solution, thanks!